# calculate distance between points and a center within a radius HIVE

Tags: hive, gis, esri

Im  using the following to get all points from my hive datbase that are within 200m of my center.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84(ST_SetSRID(ST_LineString(array(ST_Point(longitude_of_center, 
latitude_of_center), 
ST_Point(longitude_of_point, latitude_of_point))), 4326)) <= 200;
```

Please, I need also is to get the distance between the choosen points and the center as part of my query result as a new colum DIST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a LineString from each chosen point paired with the center, then call GeodesicLengthWGS84 on each such LineString.  It would be the same Length call as you have in the `where` clause, but also added to the column projections (so something like `select *, ST_GeodesicLengthWGS834(...) from ...`.

(disclosure: collaborator on [Esri Spatial Framework for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/))